# How to use driver.findElement to locate an element with below XML?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have XML as below:

```
<input name="_jpfcpncuivr___ns535482039__j_id__ctru0:fragmentRegionStatic:0:it1" maxlength="6" style="text-transform:uppercase" type="text" class="af_inputText_content" id="_jpfcpncuivr___ns535482039__j_id__ctru0:fragmentRegionStatic:0:it1::content">
```

I have tried `driver.findElement` by id, name, className, cssSelector, or xpath but all failed and got an error:

> no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: You are missing your XML and/or code.

Comment: Please share whole xml may be element is bind with iframe  .

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to locate and `click()` on the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[class$='inputText_content'][id*='fragmentRegionStatic']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'inputText_content') and contains(@id, 'fragmentRegionStatic')]"))).click();
  ```